# Refresh screen in Flutter without the user noticing

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I'm having trouble updating a particular screen on the flutter.

I need the data on this screen to be updated every 10 seconds, but without the user noticing. Every 10 seconds I run a Rest API to fetch the data, and after fetching the data the screen **'flashes'**, but I don't want that to happen, does anyone know how I can proceed?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe some snippets of your code might help, I would assume you are calling the API within a build method causing it to re-build
You can use providers and have the API call running outside of your build methods, if some information changed and you want the change to be displayed then update the data using the provider so it updates only the widgets that should update

Answer (score 0):

just Simple use

```
setState(() {});
```

if you want to refresh periodically every 10 seconds, then have this function in a

```
 Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 10, your_function))
```